# How to create controls dynamically in MVC 3 based on an database table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

controls should be created dynamically based on DB Table. and also the user's value should also be stored in DB

Comment: This question is too broad...go try some things and look at examples on asp.net and ask more specific questions when you get stuck on something

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the Database First approach, using Entity Framework.

Microsoft has [a video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg702905) on MSDN on you build an MVC3 application with the database first approach, also available in text as a [blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489).

This will generate the models you need based on your DB. The controllers will however have to be added manually I believe.